# global vs shared memory in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I have two CUDA kernels that compute similar stuff. One is using global memory (`myfun` is a device function that reads a lot from global memory and do the computation). The second kernel transfers that chunk of data from global memory to shared memory so the data can be shared among different threads of a block. My kernel that uses global memory is much faster than the one with shared memory. What are the possible reasons?

`loadArray` just copies a small part of `d_x` to `m`.

```
__global__ void mykernel(float *d_x, float *d_y, int *d_z, float *d_u, int N, int K, int D)
{

  int tid = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int index = 0;
  float max_s = 1e+37F;


  if (tid < N)
    {

      for (int i = 0; i < K; i++)
        {

          float s = myfun(&d_x[i*D], d_y, tid);

          if (s > max_s)
            {
              max_s = s;
              index = i;
            }
        }

      d_z[tid] = index;
      d_u[tid] = max_s;
    }
}
```

Using shared memory:

```
__global__ void mykernel(float *d_x, float *d_y, int *d_z, float *d_u, int N, int K)
{
  int tid = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int index = 0;
  float max_s = 1e+37F;

  extern __shared__ float m[];
  if( threadIdx.x == 0 )
    loadArray( m, d_x );
  __syncthreads();

  if (tid < N)
    {

      for (int i = 0; i < K; i++)
        {

          float s = myfun(m, d_y, tid);

          if (s > max_s)
            {
              max_s = s;
              index = i;
            }
        }

      d_z[tid] = index;
      d_u[tid] = max_s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that only the first thread in each block is reading from global memory into shared memory, this is much slower than letting all threads read from global memory simultaneously.

Using shared memory is an advantage when a single thread needs to access neighbouring elements from global memory - but this doesn't appear to be the case here.

Comment: If loading is also parallelized, everything would be perfect. Each thread loads some part to shared memory