# Constant Memory vs Texture Memory vs Global Memory in CUDA

Tags: memory, cuda, textures

I am trying to find the differences between constant memory vs texture memory vs global memory in CUDA.

I am able to find the following relevant articles, but not able to find the answer to my question

[global vs shared memory in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676311/global-vs-shared-memory-in-cuda)

[Usage of global vs. constant memory in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038286/usage-of-global-vs-constant-memory-in-cuda)

An article which deals with the performance implications of all the three :
http://forum.beyond3d.com/showthread.php?t=52510

Comment: This is pretty well explained in the CUDA Programming Guide.  Have you checked there?

Comment: What do you mean my "theoretical differences"? As written it isn't a particular specific question.........

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Constant Memory:**

This is where constants and kernel arguments are stored

Slow, but with cache (8 kb)

Constant memory is optimized for broadcast

**Texture Memory:**

Cache optimized for 2D spatial access pattern

Reads have some advantages like address modes and interpolation that can be used at no extra cost

**Global Memory:**

Slow & uncached(1.0),cached(2.0)

Requires sequential & aligned 16 byte reads and writes to be fast (coalesced read/write)

Source: http://www.cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/2011spring/gpgpu/cuda_memory.pdf